# Multiple Comparison Conditions on Sort Key for DynamoDB?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am using AWS SDK2 DynamoDB for an application with the following schema:

```
personId    startDate    endDate     name    age  job
1           10/2/2013    10/3/2020   Bob     12   SWE
1           8/2/2013     10/3/2021   Bob     12   EE
2           10/2/2013    10/3/2021   Joe     17   Student
3           11/2/2013    10/3/2022   Kim     16   Boss
```

My goal is to be able to query the table by a `personId` and a `date` in order to retrieve a person object. Currently, I am thinking about having a `partition key` on `personId`; however, I am not sure how to design my `sortKey`.

For example, say I want a `person` with `personId = 1` and `date = 10/5/2019`, I would expect the first and second entry of the example table to be returned because the date is between the `startDate` and `endDate`. How can I design the sortKey so that I can use an appropriate key condition expression to say something like date between `startDate` and `endDate`? I know that filter expression can be used, but I was wondering if there was a way to design the sort key so that filter is not needed as it is more costly.

Comment: How many rows (items) can you actually have for a given personId?

Comment: As many as you want

Comment: OK thanks, that wasn't clear from the original example.

Answer (score -2):

No you can't.

Why do you need a sort key anyway?  If personId is unique, you don't need a composite primary key (hash + sort).

And since you know the personId when reading, you can just use GetItem(table, HK=:personId)

**Edit**

Given the additional information that personId is not unique...

Have startDate be your sort key...

You'll be able to Query(table, HK=:personId, SK <= :date, ScanIndexForward=false, limit=1)

This will return the single record with the most recent start date less than or equal to the date you passed in.

The SQL equivalent would look like

```
select *
from table
where personId = :personId 
      and startDate <= :date
order by startDate desc
fetch first row only
```

**EDIT2**
Didn't see the updated info in the question.  If a person can have overlapping jobs, then you'll need to leave off the limit and do the filtering (either in DDB or in your client app)

DDB isn't the best for everything, with data as you've laid out, you've basically got two choices, pay more for DDB RCUs or pay more for an RDB.

Having said that, I'll point out that a DDB RCU covers up to 4KB of data.

If your DDB rows are smaller, you can return multiple rows with a single Query() call costing only 1 RCU.

If you're row size is 512b, you could return 8 rows for a single RCU.

Comment: Say for example that personId has multiple startDate and endDate because there is an additional field called job. The point of the sortkey is to retrieve all persons/objects with the personId and have the date be between the startDate and endDate.

Comment: Not sure the latest update actually gives the correct results. I think the date ranges for a given personId can overlap and it's possible that multiple jobs were active on the requested date. So you can't use limit=1. Plus you'd need to apply further filtering to the result set to ensure that the end date did not precede the requested date.

Comment: I didn't see the update to the post...but if it's that screwy, the OP should plan on paying a bit more in RCU in DDB and filtering (perhaps on the client side)...or paying a bit more and using an RDB..  DDB is not the best choice for everything.

Comment: Exactly what @jarmod says! I am wondering if it is possible to do this without filtering. Also, I agree that DDB is not the best choice for everything, but unfortunately it is the choice that we went with.

Comment: Thanks Charles, this is what I figured as well. No way around it by using some weird sortKey. I'll probably use filter or do something on my end.